# Prove that there exist $\alpha < 0$ and $\beta > 0$ such that $Y = [\alpha, \beta]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let
$X = \{A = (a_{ij}) \in M_2(\mathbb R): tr(A) = 0 \text{and} |a_{ij}|\leq 2 \forall i,j \}$
Let $Y = \{\det(A) : A \in X\}\subset \mathbb R.$ Then, there exist $\alpha < 0$ and $\beta > 0$ such
that $Y = [\alpha, \beta]$

My attempt.
$M_2(\mathbb R)$~$ \mathbb R^4$

$\because tr(A) = 0$. We get $a_{11}=-a_{22}.$ I know that $f:M_2(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R: f(A)=\det (A)$ is a continuous map. So, It is enough to prove that $X$ is compact. $O$ matrix is in $X$. So  matrix with $\det(A)=O$  exists.

Comment: No, you need to show your $\alpha<0$ and $\beta>0$, rather than just $\alpha\leq 0$ and $\beta\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to just break it down into the components.

We have $det(A) = a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}$. By the trace constraint we get that $det(A)=-a_{11}^2-a_{12}a_{21}$. We also know that each entry is smaller than $2$ in magnitude. Since $det(A)$ is a polynomial of these three variables (and hence continuous) and each variable lives in a compact set $[-2,2]$, the values of $det(A)$ form a compact set. More specifically, the image of the product of intervals $[-2,2]^3$ under a polynomial is an interval. Now just show that there is a matrix with $det(A)<0$ and another with $det(B)>0$ and you are done.